# Invalid identifier although the column is in the table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

The database is `Oracle 11g release2`.

There is a Spring application making connection to the above database. All the mappings are correct. At runtime when submitting a form to update a record then I get the exception `invalid identifier : some_column`. Although the column is in the table when I make a `desc command` on it through `SqlPlus` ! So how to fix that ?

Answer (score 3):

If your application encloses identifies into double quotes then case matters.

```
create table t(id1 int, id2 int);

Table created.

UPDATE T SET ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2;

0 rows updated.

update t set id1 = 1, id2 = 2;

0 rows updated.

UPDATE T SET "ID1" = 1, ID2 = 2;

0 rows updated.

update t set "id1" = 1, id2 = 2;
update t set "id1" = 1, id2 = 2
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "id1": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, identifiers (names of schemata, tables, columns, procedures, etc.) are stored in all-upper-case in the data catalog. You can write them any way you want, and you can use them any way you want in any part of your queries, functions etc.; the parser (pre-processor) re-writes them in upper-case.

This doesn't mean, though, that Oracle is case-insensitive. It is not. You may require that capitalization be preserved, by enclosing the identifier in double quotes. You did that; you probably thought it means something else.

If you define a column as `id`, `ID`, or `Id`, you can then call it by any of the three names and you will still get the desired result. However, if you call a column `"ID"`, you must then refer to it as `"ID"`, not `"id"` or `"Id"`, every time you reference it. (You may, however, refer to it as `id`, without the double quotes, since the parser will map that to `ID`, which is the same as `"ID"`.)

In fact, you can have two columns in the same table, one called `"ID"` and the other `"id"` - there is no conflict. They may contain different data - they may even be of different data type. However, you cannot have `"ID"` and `ID` (or `"ID"` and `id` - because Oracle automatically maps `id` to `ID`, as I said already).

In your case, the simple solution is, drop the double-quotes. Get in the habit of NEVER, EVER using double-quoted names; that will save you a lot of trouble.